# Script is running from .ps1 physical location not from specified path

Tags: windows-10, powershell, imagemagick

I'm working on a script that:

1. Takes an uploaded folder and removes all its folders
2. Dumps all its files into another folder
3. Converts all the files into one single .pdf using ImageMagick
4. Moves that .pdf to another folder and deletes all the other files.

I got the script to run before trying to get it to check if the folder was finished copying before running. But now I messed something up and its running the script (Just fine) but on the desktop where I have the file stored. Not with the specified directories.

All I'm trying to do is make sure the script waits until the folder is done copying in before running.

**My current Code:**

```
$freshStart = 0
$input = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop'
While ($freshStart -eq 0)
{
    $status = Get-Item $input | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {
        $input = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop'
        $output = 'C:\IT\Processing'
        $pdf = 'C:\IT\Processing\*.pdf'
        $done = 'C:\IT\Converted PDF'
        $deleteME = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop\*'
        $deleteMEToo = 'C:\IT\Processing\*'

        $folder = get-childitem -Path $input -Directory -Name

        $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"

        Get-ChildItem -Path $input -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $output
        & CD $output
        & magick "*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tif}" $fileName
        Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $done
        Remove-Item $deleteMEToo -Recurse -Force
        Remove-Item $deleteME -Recurse -Force
    }
    Else
    {
        sleep 10
        $statusOld = $status
    }

    $freshStart = 1
}


### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "$input"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true


$status = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created"
### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action =
{
    $status = Get-Item $input | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {
        $input = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop'
        $output = 'C:\IT\Processing'
        $pdf = 'C:\IT\Processing\*.pdf'
        $done = 'C:\IT\Converted PDF'
        $deleteME = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop\*'
        $deleteMEToo = 'C:\IT\Processing\*'

        $folder = get-childitem -Path $input -Directory -Name

        $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"

        Get-ChildItem -Path $input -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $output
        #& CD $output
        #Set-Location -Path '$output'
        & magick "*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tif}" $fileName
        Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $done
        Remove-Item $deleteMEToo -Recurse -Force
        Remove-Item $deleteME -Recurse -Force
    }
    Else{       
        sleep 10
        $statusOld = $status
    }
}

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**EDITED CODE (Not working):**

```
$freshStart = 0
$inLoc = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop'
$outLoc = 'C:\IT\Processing'
$pdf = 'C:\IT\Processing\*.pdf'
$done = 'C:\IT\Converted PDF'
$deleteME = 'C:\IT\Convert Drop\*'
$deleteMEToo = 'C:\IT\Processing\*'

While ($freshStart -eq 0)
{
    $status = Get-Item $inLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
    $statusOld = 0
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {

        $folder = get-childitem -Path $inLoc -Directory -Name

        $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"

        Get-ChildItem -Path $inLoc -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $outLoc
        & CD $outLoc
        & magick "*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tif}" $fileName
        Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $done
        Remove-Item $deleteMEToo -Recurse -Force
        Remove-Item $deleteME -Recurse -Force
    }
    Else
    {
        $statusOld = $status
        $status = Get-Item $inLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
        sleep 10
    }

    $freshStart = 1
}


### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "$inLoc"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true


### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action =
{
    $status = Get-Item $inLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
    $statusOld = 0
    If ($status -eq $statusOld)
    {

        $folder = get-childitem -Path $inLoc -Directory -Name

        $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"

        Get-ChildItem -Path $inLoc -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $outLoc
        #& CD $outLoc
        #Set-Location -Path '$outLoc'
        & magick "*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tif}" $fileName
        Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $done
        Remove-Item $deleteMEToo -Recurse -Force
        Remove-Item $deleteME -Recurse -Force
    }
    Else{
        $statusOld = $status
        $status = Get-Item $inLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
        sleep 10
    }
}

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**UPDATED SCRIPT**

```
#File Locations
$rootPath = 'C:\IT\'
$inLoc = 'Convert Drop'
$prossLoc = 'Processing'
$outLoc = 'Converted PDF'

#File types to include in PDF creation.
$fileTypes = '*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif}'

#Function Variables
$inPath  = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$inLoc"
$outPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$outLoc"
$runPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$prossLoc"
$remove1 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($inLoc + "\*")"
$remove2 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($outLoc + "\*")"

#Folder Watching Variables
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$inPath"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

#Lone Counter
$freshStart = $null
$statusOld  = $null
$pathLoc    = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName

#Pulls the last write time of a folder to compare later.
$grabStatus = {$status = Get-Item $pathLoc | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime } }

#Get PDF name from Folder
$grabFileName = {
    $folder = get-childitem -Path $inPath -Directory -Name
    $fileName = $folder + ".pdf"
}

#Move all nested files to single folder.
$moveFiles = {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inPath -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $runPath
}

#Convert Nested files into single PDF
$makePDF = {
    & CD $runPath
    & magick "$fileTypes" $fileName
}

#Move final PDF
$moveCmplt = {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $pdf -File | Move-Item -Destination $outPath
}

#Delete Old files
$deleteOld = {
    Remove-Item $remove1 -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item $remove2 -Recurse -Force
}

#Set compare status to current status then fetches new status.
$stats = {
    $statusOld = $status
    $grabStatus
    sleep 10
}

#Exicute main conversion together.
$action = {
    $grabStatus
    If ($status -eq $statusOld){
        $grabFileName
        $moveFiles
        & CD $runPath
        $grabStatus
        If ($status -eq $statusOld) {
            $makePDF
        }
        Else{
            $stats
        }
        $deleteOld
    }
    Else
    {
        $stats
    }
}

#First Time Start, Then Loop run.
While ($freshStart -eq $null) {
    If ((Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
    }
    Else {
        $action
    }
    $freshStart = "FreshStartDone!"
}

#Scan folder every 5 seconds for new content then run convert on change.
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: `$input` is an [automatic_variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5) I wouldn't interfere with it. I'd also move the definition of static variables outside of a while/if.

Comment: Changing the $input to a different name and moving all the static variables to the top of the script did "fix" the issue with it running at the file location, however now I get nothing at all. The rest of the script appears to be working and I get no errors, but nothing is happening?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to update the code you are using now.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated code added.

Comment: This script could use some serious refactoring and I'd try to put the logic into some functions as well setting variables outside accordingly or utilize `$script:`. If all you need to do is. . . "*make sure the script waits until the folder is done copying in before running*" then why not perform those operations that need to complete within a function and then once that function completes call another function or run some logic, etc. When your PowerShell scripts get too complex though, consider refactoring and adding in some functions to make cleaner code if you have many scripts especially.

Comment: I'm talking about defined functions within the script itself though btw. . . https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll see if I can rework the script to make it cleaner and break it apart into smaller functions bites. :)

Comment: From a quick look for another pointer example, the `$action =` variable `if` condition could simply check the status codes are equal and if true call a function that sets the folders and run the imagemagick conversions, etc. and you should be assured it'll return back control to the caller once the function completes it's operations. If you put the operations in functions and control the call order, and leave needed static variables outside of functions or utilize `$script:` scope accordingly, you can do a lot and make it easier to read and understand too at the same time. Keep scripting!!

Comment: I think I'm missing something. From my reading the $script: allows a variable to send its information back outside the function. But how do I allow outside variables inside a while, If, else, or function? That seems to be where most of my issues lie. For example I need the File path variables to pass into the function. If I place the variable at the top of the script outside the function it doesn't seem to "pickup" that variable, but it I copy paste it inside the function it works just fine. I don't necessarily need the function to change the variable just take in the info from it.

Comment: This questions has drifted away from my original question about the script running on saved location. I'll start a new question with my current script confusion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `@Tohny.Johnson` You didn't tag me back so I just saw your reply a few minutes ago. I refactored your logic some so please test with this (https://pastebin.com/Y6p6RbEj) or use something like this to do further testing. The logic that does the file copying, etc. is within the `FileOps` function and it uses static variable and only does that so call it when the `lastwrite` stamp of new folders equal `0` per the `$status -eq $statusOld` but instead of running the logic, just call the function, it'll run the logic and then come back when it is done. See if that works or helps you much.

Comment: @Tohny.Johnson Did you get a chance to look over that script logic for PowerShell on the pastebin link? Curious if it helped you any or not?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes lots of info, I just started working with powershell about three weeks ago. Lots to learn, but it's making more sense as I go. Using functions, global variables, and expanding my powershell vocabulary has helped a ton. Thank you for your assistance with all this. It's nice to get help with each "hurdle".

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Nope what you had worked perfect for what I was thinking at the time. I actually ended up making it more/less complicated later on. I eventually added a check to see if Folder is empty -> Move Files -> convert -> move PDF -> Check if PDF is in final spot -> delete all other files. All this is started when a .txt file is created called "START.txt" which I made a separate little .bat file to do that, with a message for the user.  I'll make a separate post as well with my final script with the "answer"

Comment: @Tohny.Johnson Awesome sauce!! Keep learning and trying things and using the SU community!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED Script**

```
#File Locations
$rootPath = 'C:\IT'
$inLoc = 'Convert Drop'
$prossLoc = 'Processing'
$outLoc = 'Converted PDF'

#File types to include in PDF creation.
$fileTypes = '*.{png,jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif}'

#Function Variables
$inPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$inLoc"
$outPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$outLoc"
$runPath = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$prossLoc"
$remove1 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($inLoc + "\*")"
$remove2 = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$($prossLoc + "\*")"
$global:thefile = Join-Path -Path "$rootPath" -ChildPath "$("START.txt")"

#Lone Vars
$freshStart = $null
$Global:statusOld = $null
$pathLoc = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName
$global:allClear = 'No'
$pathTaken = $null
$global:areYouThere = $null

#Pulls the last write time of a folder to compare later.
function grabStatus
{
    $global:status = Get-Item $runPath | Foreach { $_.LastWriteTime }
}

#Get PDF name from Folder
function grabFileName
{
    $folder = get-childitem -Path $inPath -Directory -Name
    $global:fileName = $folder + ".pdf"
}

#Check if Empty
function checkEmpty
{
    $directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object
    $directoryInfo.count #Returns the count of all of the files in the directory
    If ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)
    {
        $global:allClear = 'Yes'
    }
    else
    {
        sleep 5
    }
}

#Move all nested files to single folder.
function moveFiles
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $inPath -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination $runPath
}

#Convert Nested files into single PDF
function makePDF
{
    & CD $runPath
    & magick $fileTypes $global:fileName
}

#Move final PDF
function moveCmplt
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$runPath\*.pdf" -File | Move-Item -Destination $outPath
}

#Delete Old files
function deleteOld
{
    Remove-Item $remove1 -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item $remove2 -Recurse -Force
}

#Delete Empty folders
function folderClean
{
    do
    {
        $dirs = gci $inPath -directory -recurse | Where { (gci $_.fullName -Force).count -eq 0 } | select -expandproperty FullName
        $dirs | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_ }
    }
    while ($dirs.count -gt 0)
}
#Set compare status to current status then fetches new status.
function stats
{
    $Global:statusOld = $Global:status
    grabStatus
    sleep 10
}

function testPDFcreate
{
    do { sleep 5 }
    until (test-path -path ($outpath + '\$global:fileName') -eq true)
    $global:areYouThere = $true
}


#Exicute main conversion together.
function global:runIt
{
    grabFileName
    moveFiles
    folderClean
    Do { checkEmpty }
    Until ($global:allClear -eq 'Yes')
    makePDF
    grabStatus
    $global:allClear = 'No'
    Do { stats }
    Until ($Global:status -eq $Global:statusOld)
    moveCmplt
    $Global:statusOld = 'No'
    If ($global:areYouThere = $true)
    {
        deleteOld
        $global:areYouThere = $false
    }

}

while ($true)
{
    If ((Get-ChildItem $inPath | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
    {
        If (Test-Path -Path $global:thefile)
        {
            Remove-Item -Path $global:thefile
        }
        else{}
    }
    Else
    {
        If (Test-Path -Path $global:thefile)
        {
            [int]$fileSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $inPath -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
            If ($fileSize -gt 30)
            {
                Set-Content -Path $($outPath + "\Please Ask IT to Convert.txt") -Value "Please Ask IT to Convert"
                deleteOld
                Remove-Item -Path $global:thefile
            }
            else
            {
                global:runIt
                Remove-Item -Path $global:thefile
            }

        }
        else { sleep 10 }
    }
}
```